# Is there measurable function defined on unmeasurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In my textbook, Lebesgue measurable function is defined as

> for every finite $a$, the set $\{x\in E:f(x)>a\}$ is a measurable set of $R^n$.

And it further states

> $E=\{x\in E:f(x)=-\infty\}\bigcup (\bigcup\limits_{a = 1}^\infty  {\{ x \in E:f(x) >  - a\} } )$

Then if $f$ is measurable, then $\bigcup\limits_{a = 1}^\infty  {\{ x \in E:f(x) >  - a\} } $ is measurable, and $E$'s measurability is equivalent to the measurability of $\{x\in E:f(x)=-\infty\}$.

The textbook then says for simplicity we assume $\{x\in E:f(x)=-\infty\}$ is measurable for future discussion, that is, Lebesgue measurable function is assumed to be defined on a measurable set.

My questions are,

1. What does the set $\{x\in E:f(x)=-\infty\}$ look like? For example, if $f(x)=ln|x|$, then does this set $\{x\in E:f(x)=-\infty\}=\{0\}$?
2. since this is only an assumption, then $\{x\in E:f(x)=-\infty\}$ can actually be unmeasurable?
3. Is there a concrete example that shows $\{x\in E:f(x)=-\infty\}$ is unmeasurable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some answers depend on what you require from $E$ and from $f$.

If $f$ is measurable and $E$ is a measurable set, then $\{x \in E: f(x) = -\infty\}$ is measurable, because it can be written as a difference of two measurable sets: $$ \{x \in E: f(x) = -\infty\} = E - \bigcup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} f^{-1}([a,\infty))$$

If you don't require $E$ or $f$ to be measurable:

1. The set $\{x \in E: f(x) = -\infty\}$ can be anything. Just take any $V \subset E$ and define a function $f$ on $E$ with $f(x) = \infty$ if $x \in V$.
2. If the set $V$ is, for example, a [Vitali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) set, then yes, the set  $\{x \in E: f(x) = -\infty\}$ is non measurable. In this case $f$ isn't a measurable function.
3. Take a Vitali set $V$ on $[0,1]$ and define $f(x) = -\infty$ for $x on V$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in [0,1]-V$